# jQuery - Remove class from all div's except the one I clicked on

Tags: jquery, html

I have some code working, that toggles the class "active" on and off when you click on a swatch-wrapper div.

However I would only like **one** of these div's to have the active class at a time. Right now I could click them all, and they would all have the active class. I'm not sure how to remove the class from all the other div's except for the one I just clicked on.

I tried to use .parent(), but it didn't seem to work / I don't think I was using it correctly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="variation_form_section">
  <div class="select">
    <div class="swatch-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="swatch-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="swatch-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".variation_form_section .select div").each(function() { 
      $(this).click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass( "active" )){
            $(this).removeClass( "active" );
        }else{
            $(this).addClass( "active" );
        }
      });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) like this:

```
$(".variation_form_section .select div").click(function() { 
  $(".variation_form_section .select div").not($(this)).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Why each loop? This code is going to set as active the last element.

Answer (score 20):

Simply, remove `active` class from them all and then add `active` class to the clicked element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".variation_form_section .select div").click(function() { 
      $('.variation_form_section .select div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/conm54k2/

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz Nowak, but this get's rid of the toggle function as well. I would still like it to remove 'active' if I click on an already active div. I tried adding my if statement, but it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/conm54k2/1/

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. You want to create toggle effect (http://jsfiddle.net/conm54k2/2/) or just do it with checking current status (http://jsfiddle.net/conm54k2/3/)?

Comment: how about both at the same time @MateuszNowak  ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to toggle if the div is already active, you just have to check it before clearing all the actives. After that, only add an active state if the clicked div was not originally active.

http://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/6208d114/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".variation_form_section .select div").click(function() {
      var isActive = ($(this).hasClass('active')) ? true : false; // checks if it is already active
      console.log("isActive: "+isActive);
      $('.variation_form_section .select div').removeClass('active');
      if(!isActive) $(this).addClass('active'); // set active only if it was not active
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with .siblings() http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $(".variation_form_section .select div").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }); 
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/conm54k2/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".swatch-wrapper").on('click',function() { 
     $(".swatch-wrapper").removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 
});
</script>
```